# CSS Media query for iOS device not working?

Tags: css, ios, ipad

I'm using the below styles to try and customize my site on iPad (10th generation, 10.2"). But for some reason when I hit the site on the iPad, none of the styles are picked up. Even when I use Safari's develop tool, it doesn't seem to see any of the CSS I've put into the stylesheet:

```
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <style>
    
    
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3)
  and (orientation: portrait) { 
  
    
    
    .master-container {
    
    scale: 1.0 !important;
    margin-top: -310px !important;
    
    }
    
    .logo {
    
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 0%;
    width: 99%;
    
    }
    
    .welcome-fb {
    
    width: 99%;
    padding-left: 0%;
    text-align: center;
    
    }
    
    }
    
    </style>
    
    </head>
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? Oddly, my CSS with orientation landscape using the exact same @media structure DOES appear on the iPad...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution. Posting it incase it helps anyone else! The below works for the 10th Gen iPad!

```
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1)
  and (orientation: portrait) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `min/max-width` instead; `device-width` has been [depreciated](https://drafts.csswg.org/mediaqueries-4/#mf-deprecated) since 2018.

Comment: Gave it a try, still no dice :/